# Why is the support of a measure closed?

Tags: measure-theory

I found the following statement on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory))

> The support of a measure is closed in $X$ as its complement is the union of the open sets of measure 0.

where $X$ is from a topological space $(X, T)$ and the mentioned measure, call it $\mu$, is on the space $(X, \mathcal{B}(T))$.

Why are the sets of measure zero open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not mean that all sets with measure $0$ are open, but that the complement of the support is the union of open sets with measure $0$.

See the definition of the support:

> the support (or spectrum) of $μ$ is defined as the set of all points $x$
>   in $X$ for which every **open neighbourhood** $N_x$ of $x$ has positive measure

This means that if $x\not\in supp (\mu)$, there exists $N_x$ an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $\mu(N_x)=0$. Hence the property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense! But why isn't the opposite true as well then, i.e. why is the support not an union of open sets with measure > 0? By reasoning that if $x \in supp (\mu)$, there exists $N_x$ an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $\mu(N_x)>0$?

Comment: The definition says that this must be true for any open neighborhood of $x$, which is stronger.