# support of measure have a full measure if $X$ is a Hausdorff and $\mu$ is a Radon measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This statement is in Wiki:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Properties

Note that the definition of support of measure is
$$\operatorname{supp}\mu =\{x: \forall N\text{ open neighborhood of}\,x, \mu(N)>0\}.$$
Then, this statement is that
$$\mu(X-supp\mu)=0.$$

Although for every $x\in X-supp\mu$, there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ which is measure zero, it seems to me that it does not imply to the above equation.

If this is a hard problem, assume that $X=\mathbb{R}^d$ with a standard metric. Thank you.

Comment: Your definition of support does not make sense.

Comment: Typically the support if a measure $\mu$ on a topological space I defined as $$\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=\{x\in X: \forall U\,\text{open}, \,x\in U\,\text{implies}\, \mu(U)>0\}$$
Some other textbooks defined support as the largest closed set $C\subset X$ such that $\mu(X\setminus C)=0$. For second countable spaces both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @lee: this question and similar ones have been addressed at MSE before. Some of them have answers which may be useful for you. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445115/121671) is an example

Comment: @Oliver Diaz : Thank you. I understand your explanation.